# Android smart phone wont turn ON

Tags: battery, charging

[image]
When I try to turn On my LG L7, it shows

> Device temperature too high or low. Please move to another place to charge.

And it wont turn ON. 
It started after I tried to measure voltage between the electrodes where the battery goes using a multimeter.
I think I messed up it by shorting positive and negative.
What can I do? Please help

Comment: May be you killed the temperature sensor of the battery. Remove the battery and wait for an hour. Then try again. If it does not work you may have to replace the battery.

Comment: It doesnt work. Is there anything I can do. I think I must have damaged the charging module of the main board

Comment: What does not work? Replacing the battery?

Comment: yeah. Replacing the battery